# I don't receive Hudson job's e-mail notifications

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I configured Hudson jobs to notify me and/or my group about failing builds, so I basically checked job's options "E-mainl Notification", "Send e-mail for every unstable build", "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build" + I added my e-mail/SVN username/my group e-mail in all possible configurations. **None** of these recipient got an e-mail from Hudson after the failed build. The job's log says: "Sending e-mails to: --list of all adrresses to send--" so he claims it is all correct.

What's interesting, when I go to Hudson's global configuration and insert the very same addresses as "System Admin E-mail Address" + hit "Test configuration..." I/my group **do receive** the emails.

PS. My Hudson's version is 1.353.

Please help :)

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Yeah, it's empty. I think it might be some bizarre SMTP server problem though...